# Best way to store shared files between ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

My website supports uploading images by the users. I'm trying to figure out what is the best strategy to save those files given that I have more than one ec2 instance running. Amazon Elastic File System sounds perfect but it's still in preview mode. What is the best alternative?

Answer (score 3):

You almost certainly want to use S3 to share images between EC2 instances unless you have some very unique circumstances that won't allow it.

Best to not store any user data on the instance itself if you can avoid it; makes it easier to scale and to recover from crashes. S3 is a perfect super-redundant place to keep 'stuff' that costs next to nothing.

Comment: I would add that you should also look into uploading those files directly from your users into S3, rather than proxying the upload through your web servers. And similarly, when the files are later consumed, have them downloaded directly from S3 to the user. Look at S3 pre-signed URLs, for example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Comment: or use a 3rd party service like [uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com) to avoid this problem altogether.